# Error when trying to query the DB on whether a user input is like 2 other fields in the DB

Tags: php, sql

I have this:

```
// if there is a plant name
if (isset($_POST['plant_name']) && $_POST['plant_name']) {
$where .= "AND LOWER(common_name) LIKE '".strtolower($_POST['plant_name']) "OR LOWER(latin_name) LIKE '".strtolower($_POST['plant_name'])."%' ";
}
```

I have a user input field called plant name on my form. When a user enters something in, I want to check to see if it is LIKE a value in the common_name field in the database or LIKE a value in the latin_name field in the database.

My error is:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

which is pointing at line 53 which is this line:

```
$where .= "AND LOWER(common_name) LIKE '".strtolower($_POST['plant_name']) "OR LOWER(latin_name) LIKE '".strtolower($_POST['plant_name'])."%' ";
```

Comment: you're missing `'` and a space before OR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `.` in PHP, and a `'` in your query:

```
$where .= "AND LOWER(common_name) LIKE '".strtolower($_POST['plant_name']) . "' OR LOWER(latin_name) LIKE '".strtolower($_POST['plant_name'])."%' ";
                                                                           ^  ^
```

Also, if you're using MySQL, `LIKE` is case-insensitive so you don't need to use `LOWER`.

And you should at least escape your user inputs with `mysql_real_escape_string`, or use prepared statements (better choice): http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Prepared statement example:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` ';
$bindParams = array( );
$where = array( );

// if the post variable is set...
if( isset( $_POST['plant_name'] ) && !empty( $_POST['plant_name'] ) {
    // add the value to $bindParams
    $bindParams['plant_name'] = $_POST['plant_name'];
    // add the where clause to the array
    $where[] = 'common_name LIKE :plant_name OR latin_name LIKE :plant_name';
}

// do similar if blocks for other post variables

// build the where array into a string
if( count( $where ) > 0 )
    $query .= 'WHERE (' . implode( ') AND (', $where ) . ')';

// prepare and execute
$stmt = $db->prepare( $query );
if( $stmt->execute( $bindParams ) ) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I understand prepared statements and I have them everywhere else in my code - but I am unsure how to do the syntax for a prepared statement in this type of code because it is slightly different to a normal query if you know what I mean

Comment: @user1227124 I added an example for you for building this type of query dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

This is nasty, parameterise your queries. Avoid this problem and SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
$where .= " AND LOWER(common_name) LIKE '".strtolower($_POST['plant_name']) . "' OR LOWER(latin_name) LIKE '".strtolower($_POST['plant_name'])."%' ";
```

You were missing a space and single quote after `strtolower($_POST['plant_name'])`.
I added a space before `AND` for good measure.